# Вывод текста через значение Select

Tags: javascript, input, select

Имеется input, отвечающий за отображение указанного текста в данном input

```
<input type="text" name="upc" value="<?php echo $upc; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_upc; ?>" id="input-upc" class="form-control" />
```

Как сделать через Select к примеру, если значение равно 1 то вывод определённого текста, если 0 то пустое поле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готовое решение для Opencart, для тех кто не хочет постоянно вводить одно и тоже значение

```
<select name="upc" id="input-upc" class="form-control">
                <?php if ($upc) { ?>
                <option value="">Нет</option>
                <option value="Экслюзив" selected="selected">Да</option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="">Нет</option>
                <option value="Экслюзив">Да</option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input-upc');
let select = document.getElementById('select-upc');

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
   if(select.value == 0) {
       input.setAttribute("value", "");
   } 
   else {
       input.setAttribute("value", "выводим " + this.value);   
   };
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="upc" value="" id="input-upc" class="form-control" />
<select id="select-upc">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: подскажите, а как сделать через только через select, без input

Comment: Не совсем понял, можете более конкретно пояснить, что именно вам нужно

Comment: у меня есть вот такой код для mpn
<select name="mpn" id="input-mpn" class="form-control">
<?php if ($mpn) { ?>
<option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
<option value="0"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
 <?php } else { ?>
<option value="1"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
 <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
?php } ?>
</select>

как сделать на примере кода сверху, где 1 это вывод заготовленного текста в  $result['upc'], а 0 пустое значение

Comment: при значении Да, вывод текста в  $result['upc'], при значении Нет пустое поле в  $result['upc']

Comment: Честно, я бы вам помог, но не понимаю вопрос до конца, что именно вам требуется

Comment: Движок Opencart. В данном input, что код сверху при вводе текста, выводит данное поле вместе в div. Постоянно вводить текст "Эксклюзив" будет трудновато. Хочется вывести Select с простыми опциями Да и Нет, где Да будет выводить текст в $result['upc'], при значении Нет будет пустое поле

Comment: А `$result['upc']` это что у вас, обычный `div`?

Comment: нет, $result['upc'] это вывод значения UPN  в Opencart в карточке определённого товара

Comment: "Да будет выводить текст в $result['upc']"; 
 
" $result['upc'] это вывод значения UPN" - вы меня окончательно запутали